# Reading EM4102 RFID tags on android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I'm exploring the possibilities of using the NFC Antenna on my Nexus 4 to read membership cards at work. The cards are an EM4102 RFID tag.

I found a small app called NFC Reader on the Android Market, but it doesn't react to the card, but it reads another tag (Mifare I think) perfectly fine.

Would this be a miss in the software, or is the antenna unable to read EM4102 tags?

I'm working on a small test app to see if I can get it working, but if anyone here has any experience with this, it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with those tags, but [a quick Google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=EM4102) suggests they are 125kHz technology. [NFC only supports 13.56MHz technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication).

Comment: This just hit me too. Sadly this is probably the issue.